# count number of all rows in the table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel. I have a table named as **projects** and, I need to count number of all rows of the projects table. I have tried using `id` column to count all the rows like the following function

```
public function totalprojects()
    {
        $projects = Project::where('id')->count();

        return view('summarys.summary')->withProjects($projects);
    }
```

but its returning **0** how can I manage this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your controller

**(1) using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) :**

```
 use App\Project;

 public function totalprojects()
        {
            $total_projects = Project::count();
            return view('summarys.summary')->with(['total'=>$total_projects]);
        }
```

**(2) using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) :**

```
  use DB;
  public function totalprojects()
            {
                $total_projects = DB::table('projects')->count();
                return view('summarys.summary')->with(['total'=>$total_projects]);
            }
```

in your blade :

```
<p>{{ $total }}</p>
```